# RIA Services and Linq2Sql

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I have a Product object with a property that is a collection of type Workflows.  In my "GetProducts" method on the domaincontext object I have set a breakpoint at the return statement to see if the workflows collection is filled.

It is.

On the client side I check Context.Products[0].Workflows in another breakpoint and I see 0 results.  Is there a way to persist this nested data for consumption on the client side or is RIA Services inhibited from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should kick myself.  I realized that I needed to add "[Include]" to the property in Product within the DataService.metadata.cs file and now it gets sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you have or can download the RiaServicesOverviewPreview.pdf document section 4.8 details how to do this. The basic summary it.

1. Make sure your L2S query specifies the .LoadWith<>() parameter. Lazy loading doesn't work with RIA services so you have to use implicit loading.
2. You need to apply the "IncludeAttribute" to the associated member. For example add the [Include] attribute on your Workflows field in the Product metadata class.
3. Ensure that your Workflow (child) type is exposed as a client type so it gets genned to the client side.

You can get the document here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=76bb3a07-3846-4564-b0c3-27972bcaabce&displaylang=en